# Current logged in user for GI / Reports in 4.2

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica 4.2, is there a method to get the currently logged in user for a GI and reports?

The "@me" was introduced in 5.x but I believe there was a way to do it before.

We need to create GI's and Reports such as "My Customers" that shows all business accounts where the current user is the owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the AccessInfo table to your GI or report (cross-join) and you'll find the information you need.

Comment: that works perfect for GI's.    Reports complain about 'AccessInfo' not being valid table - looks like it's trying to pass it onto the actual SQL query.    I can add a param in the report that =AccessInfo.UserID without adding it to the tables/relationships.  that seems to show the right value, just need to figure out how to add it to the filter

Comment: Looks like you don't need to add it to tables in your report and that you can use it right away. Have a look at existing reports to see how it's used, the username of the user prints in the upper left part of every report.

Comment: What i'm having trouble with is getting the field to set the default value.   Iv I add a default value of say =[AccessInfo.UserID], it shows the user GUID however when using that Parameter (@OwnerID for example) in the Filters, it passes a null to the SQL Server.   If I specify the view name of say =Report.GetFieldSchema('CROpportunity.OwnerID'), it runs correctly when I manually set it however can't find the right default value to enter to set it to the current user.