# Determining Current User for Generic Inquiry

Tags: acumatica

I want to create a number of generic inquiries that lists the leads or other items for the user that's currently logged into Acumatica.

The answer to the question [Current logged in user for GI / Reports in 4.2] ([Current logged in user for GI / Reports in 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467211/current-logged-in-user-for-gi-reports-in-4-2)) does not work for me in a generic inquiry. It works as described for reports. 
We are using Acumatica 5.20.1757.

Using only PX.Data.AccessInfo in the generic inquiry results in the error: Sequence contains no elements. Using it in a cross join with another table gives: "Invalid object name: AccessInfo. What don't I understand/know?

Comment: If you are on more recent versions, AccessInfo will work for you in G.I, all of the fields will be blank.  You can get the UserID guid with `@me` and ended up with a condition (for Sales Order Owner): `SO.OwnerID Equals @me` leaving From Schema unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just designed a generic inquiry that lists all sales orders created by the user currently logged in for a customer that uses 4.2 of Acumatica. Here are the steps.

1. At the **Tables** tab of the Generic Inquiry screen, 2 tables need to be added in addition of the other desired tables (in this example, SO.SOOrder): Data.AccessInfo and SM.Users.
2. At the **Relations** tab, the table relation should be created between the desired tables and SM.Users. The Join Type must be Left. Ex.: SOOrder Left Join Users.
3. The **relation** must be established using the pKID field of the Users table. Ex.: SOOrder.CreatedByID Equals Users.pKID.
4. At the **Parameters** tab, add a line and give it a name like UserName. The Schema Field would then be AccessInfo.UserName. The From Schema option must be activated.
5. At the **Conditions** tab, the Data Field Users.UserName Equals the parameter added in #4 as the value.
6. If you do not want the user to change the default username defined as parameter, make sure to review the **access rights** of that field in the different roles.

Answer (score 4):

While the answer above worked quite well, this gets rid of the need to select a name and configure access rights. The following example uses leads.

Provide values for **Site Map Title** and **Site Map Location**, found just below the **Inquiry Title** field/

1. On the **Tables** tab, select PX.Data.AccessInfo, PX.Objects.CR.Contact, PX.Object.EP.EPEmployee, PX.SM.LoginTrace, and PX.SM.Users. Accept the defaults for the alias, which will populate once you leave the line.
2. On the **Relations** tab:

a) set, **Active** checked, **Parent Table** Contact **Join Type ** Left **Child Table** EPEmployee, **Parent Field** ownerID **Condition** Equals **Child Field** pKID

b)  set **Active** checked, **Parent Table** Users **Join Type ** Inner **Child Table** EPEmployee, **Parent Field** contactID **Condition** Equals **Child Field** defContactID

c)  set **Active** checked, **Parent Table** Users **Join Type ** Inner **Child Table** LoginTrace, **Parent Field** username **Condition** Equals **Child Field** username

3. On the **Parameters** tab set **Name ** to Username, **Schema Field** to AccessInfo.UserName and **Display Name ** to User Name. Active should not be checked unless you want to check the value of the field.
4. 9 lines were set to meet my specific conditions. Here they are.

a) **Active** True, **Start Brackets** (, **Data Field** Users.IsOnline **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** True, **Value 1** True, **End Brackets** , **Operator** And

b) **Active** True, **Start Brackets** , **Data Field** LoginTrace.ScreenID **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** False, **Value 1** GI000009 (yours might be different),  **End Brackets** , **Operator** And

c) **Active** False, **Start Brackets** , **Data Field** LoginTrace.Date **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** False, **Value 1** Now(), **End Brackets** ), **Operator** And

d) **Active** True, **Start Brackets** , **Data Field** Users.UserName **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** False, **Value 1** =[LoginTrace.Username], **End Brackets** , **Operator** And

e) **Active** False, **Start Brackets** , **Data Field** LoginTrace.Username **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** False, **Value 1** =[EPEmployee.UserID], **End Brackets** , **Operator** And

f) **Active** True, **Start Brackets** ((, **Data Field** Contact.ContactType **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** FALSE, **Value 1** LD, **End Brackets** , **Operator** Or

g) **Active** True, **Start Brackets** , **Data Field** Contact.ContactType **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** FALSE, **Value 1** PN, **End Brackets** ), **Operator** And

g) **Active** True, **Start Brackets** , **Data Field** Contact.Status **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** True, **Value 1** Converted, **End Brackets** , **Operator** Or

h) **Active** True, **Start Brackets** , **Data Field** Contact.Status **Condition** Equals, **From Schema** True, **Value 1** Open, **End Brackets** ), **Operator** Or

5. On the **Grouping** tab, set **Active** to True, and **Data Field** to Contact.ContactID

Sort order, results grid, and Entry point are up to you.

Notes: I found this GI failed in a different query where the LoginTrace.ScreenID condition was left out. It was not tried with left joins for the inner joins, but should have worked.